# Google Duplicate title tags and Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, seo

I'm having some problems solving duplicate title tag issues with my Wordpress installation. I have All in one SEO installed and my robots.txt looks like this;

```
User-agent:  *
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /wp-content/
Disallow: /wp-content/plugins/
Disallow: /wp-includes/
Disallow: /comments/feed/
Disallow: /feed/
Disallow: /trackback/
Disallow: /index.php
Disallow: /xmlrpc.php
Disallow: ?comments=*
Disallow: /search?
Disallow: /?p=*
Disallow: /go/


User-agent: Mediapartners-Google*
Allow: /

User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Allow: /wp-content/uploads/

User-agent: Adsbot-Google
Allow: / 

User-agent: Googlebot-Mobile
Allow: /
```

Within Google webmaster tools it seems to think I have pagination on my homepage which I don't. I'm getting duplicate titles on the following but, I have no pagination and they all show the home page.

```
/
/page/18/
/page/22/
/page/24/
```

Could I just 301 all the duplicate urls to the main homepage url?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how Google found these URLs.  Maybe you had pagination at one point (googlebot never forgets URLs).  Maybe some other site links to them.   Maybe a user visited the pages and Google took notice through the Google toolbar.  Maybe googlebot just tries URLs like this on sites that run Wordpress.

Serving the homepage on these URLs appears to be the way that Wordpress works.  I just tested these URLs on my own Wordpress site and they also show the home page.

As you suggest, you could redirect them in your .htaccess file.  It might be easier to install one of the many SEO plugins for Wordpress that put canonical tags on all of your pages.